# No such Table exist - Using SQLitePlugin in ionic app

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am newbie in ionic and working on an application in which i need to store data to local database. I am using SQLite plugin("https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git"). But it gives an error while inserting values to table - "No such Table exist". The code is mentioned below. Please let me know what's the problem.Thanks.

app.js -

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {



                             if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

                             cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                             cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
                             }
                             if(window.StatusBar) {
                             StatusBar.styleDefault();
                             }

                             db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"nextflow.db", location:'default'});

                            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baseUrl TEXT, loginId TEXT, id TEXT)');

                             });
        });
```

controller.js -

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'INSERT INTO Registration (baseUrl) VALUES (?)', [baseurl])
                                                     .then(function(result) {
                                                           console.log("Message saved successful, cheers!");


                                                           }, function(error) {
                                                           alert("Error on     saving: " + error.message);
                                                           });
```

Comment: try with re installing the app....if u face the same make sure your crating the table some where and if its there check the table name

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your app.js code to the below. I believe your syntax might be incorrect. Another possibility is that your CREATE isn't finishing execution  before you call the INSERT.

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"nextflow.db", location:'default'});

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baseUrl TEXT, loginId TEXT, id TEXT)');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
        }, function() {
            console.log('Created table OK');
        });

    });
});
```

And changing your controler.js to below,

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.execute('INSERT INTO Registration (baseUrl) VALUES (?)', [baseurl]);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Error on     saving: ' + error.message);
        }, function() {
            console.log('Message saved successful, cheers!');
        });
```

Make sure the `db` variable is accessible from both parts of the code. Typically I'll make it global, much easier.

**--EDIT--**

When you're trying to execute SQL using `tx.execute`, you must wrap your execute calls in a `db.transatcion` function. Like below,

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProfileDetail (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baseUrl TEXT, loginId TEXT, id TEXT)')
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
}, function() {
    console.log('Created table OK');
});
```

Also, I usually do all the table creations together in one area of the program. The below code would create both your tables in one transaction,

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baseUrl TEXT, loginId TEXT, id TEXT)');
    tx.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProfileDetail (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baseUrl TEXT, loginId TEXT, id TEXT)')
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
}, function() {
    console.log('Created tables OK');
});
```

Comment: ..It gives an error when i tried it changing table name. Transaction ERROR: tx.execute is not a function. (In 'tx.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProfileDetail (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, baseUrl TEXT, loginId TEXT, id TEXT)')', 'tx.execute' is undefined)

Comment: You must follow the same pattern as above. Surround your tx.execute functions in a db.transaction function. View my edit above, I'll use your new error as an example.